# Ordenar en c# una cadena de string que contiene enteros y float

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo como entrada un string que leo de un excel en c#. Debo ordenar el string por el número de la columna.

```
 int colum = 0;
 int colum1 = 1;
 string data = "alex,1,4.6\njuan,5,2.7\ncarlos,1.3,2.6\nandre,16,-2.5";
```

Aqui separo la terminación de línea

```
var values = datos.Split('\n');
```

Con split obtengo esto
values=[alex,1,4.6], [juan,5,2.7], [carlos,1.3,2.6], [andre,16,-2.5]

Esto es lo que tengo que va bien hasta un momento, hasta que me compara en la columna 1 y me encuentro con números y solo me está comparando el 1er número. Ejemplo entre 5 y 16 me dice que 16 es menor.

```
 var consult = from line in values
               let fields = line.Split(',')
               orderby fields[1] ascending
               select line;
```

Salida del string por la columna 0 que me ordena por nombres

values=[alex,1,4.6],[andre,16,-2.5],[carlos,1.3,2.6],[juan,5,2.7]

Salida del string por la columna 1 que me ordena por nombres

values=[alex,1,4.6],[carlos,1.3,2.6],[andre,16,-2.5],[juan,5,2.7]

Comment: Tu problema parece sencillo pero no se te entiende, revisa tu redaccion y pon un ejemplo del resultado q esperas, edita tu pregunta y arregla todo eso

Comment: Hola, ya edité la pregunta y muchas gracias de antemano, salu2

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que la instrucción `let fields = line.Split(',')` devuelve un `string[]`, por lo que sus valores se están ordenando alfabéticamente.

Si transformas los valores a `double` se ordenarán correctamente, por ejemplo reemplazando `orderby fields[1] ascending` por `orderby Convert.ToDouble(fields[1]) ascending`

Comment: Hola amigo y muchas gracias por realizar el aporte a la respuesta, con la opción: orderby Convert.ToDouble(fields[1]) ascending  la salida es asi : alex,1,4.6juan,5,2.7carlos,1.3,2.6andre,16,-2.5 todavía no satisface, no se que está fallando.

Answer (score 0):

@jacdDev
Muchas gracias amigo, ya pude corregir el problema, lo estaba convirtiendo a float pero tampoco satisfacía el error que me daba y lo corregí asi:

```
var consult = from line in values
              let fields = line.Split(',')
              orderby float.Parse(fields[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat) ascending
              select line;
```

Salida: values=[alex,1,4.6],[carlos,1.3,2.6],[juan,5,2.7],[andre,16,-2.5]